# How does C++ with different sources know which class to use outside of main.cpp

Tags: c++

I'm trying to grasp an understanding of c++ and i was wondering how does main.cpp know if the classes I built are in another source file?  Does the compiler automatically know if I include a header with function parameters within a class, it'll look it up on all my source files outside of main.cpp?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Short answer:** It doesn't know.

**Long answer:**
Let's say you have the following files:

## main.cpp

```
#include "A.h"

int main() {
    A a;
    a.f();
}
```

## A.h

```
class A {
    void f();
};
```

## A.cpp

```
#include "A.h"

A::f()
{
    // does something
}
```

When you invoke this command to compile `main.cpp`:

```
g++ -c main.cpp -o main.o
```

Your compiler is trusting your word that the method `A::f` is defined somewhere else. But actually the compiler doesn't know, it just trusts.

Later, you invoke this command to compile `A.cpp`:

```
g++ -c A.cpp -o A.o
```

And at this moment the compiler has no idea of how you are going to use this class (it doesn't know about the existence of `main.cpp` nor `main.o`).

All that "linking magic" will happen when you execute this command:

```
g++ main.o A.o -o ./myexe
```

At that moment the magic happens in the `linker`, it finds that `main.o` is referencing some clase called `A` that is defined somewhere else, and then it finds a file called `A.o` that contains the definition of a class with the same name `A`. So, it finds out that this and that `A` classes are the same, and does the proper linkage.

Of course you don't need to execute those three commands if you don't want to, as the following is just equivalent:

```
g++ main.cpp A.cpp -o ./myexe
```

Answer (score 3):

The compiler doesn't know. So you have to manually add all the compiled object files to the command which links the executable together.

`gcc` (and other compilers) are happy to compile multiple files with a single compiler invocation, in which case it will combine all the compiled objects. Or you can compile several files and also provide object files for linking.

But however you do it, it's your responsibility to indicate where all the files are.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you should understand early on with C++ - nothing is automatic :-)

I assume you are working within an IDE, as using GNU command line tools makes it impossible not to understand this step!

Basically, your toolchain is configured to know what directories to search in for source files and what directories to search for header files. The preprocessor is responsible for concatenating header files today, using the path indicated in the `#include` directive (unless you specify a standard header, then it searches a configurable list of directories).

When a cpp file is compiled, it generates an object file. This object file can have references to types that it doesn't know about yet - the linking phase handles wiring that up.

Here's an example.

Given the following files:

SpecialClass.h

```
#ifndef SPECIAL_CLASS_H_
#define SPECIAL_CLASS_H_
class SpecialClass {
  private:
    unsigned int x;
  public:
    SpecialClass();
    /** Increment the 'x' value and return it */
    int incrementAndReturn();
};
#endif
```

SpecialClass.cpp

```
#include "SpecialClass.h"

int SpecialClass::incrementAndReturn() {
  return this->x++;
}

SpecialClass::SpecialClass() {
  this->x = 0;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

/**
 * By including SpecialClass.h, the compiler can enforce the contract
 * outlined in the SpecialClass header. That is, if I try to use a
 * method or member that doesn't exist in the SpecialClass type, then
 * the compiler can warn me.
 */
#include "SpecialClass.h"
int main(int, char**) {

  SpecialClass foo = SpecialClass();
  std::cout << foo.incrementAndReturn() << std::endl;
}
```

I can incrementally build this, doing what the compiler seems to do in a single step:

```
rdahlgren@athas:~/work/cpp $ g++ -c main.cpp
```

At this point, main.cpp has been compiled and assembled, but has no linkage to the code defined in SpecialClass.cpp - it is unlinked.

```
rdahlgren@athas:~/work/cpp $ g++ -c SpecialClass.cpp
rdahlgren@athas:~/work/cpp $ ls -l
total 20
-rw-r--r-- 1 rdahlgren rdahlgren  410 Feb 26 23:49 main.cpp
-rw-r--r-- 1 rdahlgren rdahlgren 2672 Feb 26 23:50 main.o
-rw-r--r-- 1 rdahlgren rdahlgren  139 Feb 26 23:50 SpecialClass.cpp
-rw-r--r-- 1 rdahlgren rdahlgren  222 Feb 26 23:46 SpecialClass.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 rdahlgren rdahlgren 1448 Feb 26 23:51 SpecialClass.o
```

You can see here that I now have object files (*.o) for SpecialClass and main. These are compiled and assembled, but unlinked.

```
rdahlgren@athas:~/work/cpp $ g++ main.o SpecialClass.o -o main
```

GCC is able to link together object files as seen above, this binds the call to `incrementAndReturn` (among others).

```
rdahlgren@athas:~/work/cpp $ ./main
0
```

For a better explanation, I suggest using your favorite web search to look for information about "C++ compilation steps".